# Pointer indirection when pointer and data widths differ

Tags: c, pointers, casting, 64-bit

I want to access a 32-bit data pointed to by an address in a hardware register (which is 64 bits, with only 40 LSb's set). So I do:

```
paddr_t address = read_hw(); // paddr_t is unsigned long long
unsigned int value  = *(unsigned int*) address; // error: cast to pointer from integer of different size
unsigned int value2 = (unsigned int) *((paddr_t*) address); // error: cast to pointer from integer of different size
```

What would be the *right* way to do this without compiler error (I use `-Werror`)?

Answer (score 1):

Nominally with C99 the first option is closest to correct,

```
uint32_t value = *(uint32_t*)address;
```

However you may also choose to use the other pointer/integer helpers,

```
uintptr_t address = read_hw();
uint32_t value = *(uint32_t*)address;
```

Answer (score 0):

check the real sizes for your pointers and paddr_t type:

```
printf("paddr_t size: %d, pointer size: %d\n",
       sizeof(paddr_t), sizeof(unsigned int *));
```

what do you get?

**update:**

ARM is a 32 bits architecture, so you are trying to convert from a 64bits integer to a 32bits pointer an your compiler doesn't like it!

If you are sure that the value in paddr_t fits in a 32bits pointer you can just cast it to an `int` first:

```
unsigned int *p = (unsigned int *)(int)addrs;
```

Comment: I failed to add that I'm using a cross-compiler. So I don't have the luxury of printf!

Comment: You had better figure out a way to get debug messages out of your target - otherwise how are you going to verify more obscure parts of your code?

Comment: @Jeenu: what _is_ your target? Any chance you could use an emulator?

Comment: It's ARM hardware which is not my disposal right now. I was just making some modifications when the GCC cross compiler caught me.

Maybe if there's a way where I can hint compiler not to consider pointers as 32-bit, it'd help me.

Comment: @Jeenu: Perhaps qemu could help you? http://wiki.qemu.org/download/qemu-doc.html#ARM-System-emulator

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question.

"I want to access a 32-bit data pointed to by an address in a hardware register (which is 64 bits, with only 40 LSb's set)."

So you have a hardware register 64 bits wide, the least significant 40 of which should be interpreted as an address in memory which contains 32 bits of data?

Can you try

```
uint32_t* pointer = (*(uint64_t *) register_address) & (~0 >> 24)
uint32_t value = *pointer
```

Although this might get more complicated depending on endian-ness and whether the compiler interprets `>>` as a logical or arithmetic right-shift.

Although, really, I want to ask,

1. Does "I am using a cross-compiler, I don't have the luxury of printf" mean you can't actually run your code, or just that you have to do it some some hardware that lacks a convenient output channel?
2. What is your target architecture, that your pointers are 40 bits long?!

Answer (score 0):

From what you have written you have a 64 pointer of which only 40 bits are the pointer, and that pointer points to some data that is 32 bits in size.

Your code seems to be trying to mangle the 40 bit pointer into a 32 bit pointer.

What you should be doing is &'ing the relevant 40 bits within the 64 bit pointer so that it remains a 64 bit pointer, and then using that to access the data, which you can then similarly & to get the data. Otherwise you are (as the errors indicate) truncating the pointer.

Something like (I don't have 64 bit so I can't test this, but you get the idea):

```
address = address & 0x????????????????; // use the ?s to mask off the bits you
                                        // want to ignore
value64 = *address; // value64 is 64 bits

value32 = (int)(value64 & 0x00000000ffffffff); // if the data is in the lower
                                               // half of value64
or
value32 = (int)((value64 & 0xffffffff00000000) > 32); // if the data is in the
                                                      // higher half of value64
```

where the ?'s are masking the bits as needed (depending on the endiness that you are working with).

You'll probably also need to change the (int) casts to suit (you want to instead cast it to whatever 32 bit data type the data represents - ie. the type of value32).